# Using AWS SQS and Lambda for queue job in Laravel

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I wonder whether there is a way to use only lambda function when I dispatched a job in laravel.

What I'm using is below.

- Laravel 5.8(PHP 7.2)
- AWS SQS
- Supervisord

In Laravel, I dispatch a job with SQS connection and job is in Laravel project.
I searched how I can use SQS as a trigger for lambda function. And I found this document. ( [Using AWS Lambda with Amazon SQS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html)
 )
If I follow this document, I think I can run job in lambda. But In Laravel project, job will be run again. I want to use only lambda as a job.

How I can run only lambda function as a job?

Answer (score 2):

No it is not possible. `Sqs`, `database` or `redis` are just for keeping the serialized(encoded etc) version of your laravel jobs. Here is the closest you may get;

- Forget about sqs queue driver.
- Implement your job in aws lambda.
- Allow lambda to consume your sqs (policies, triggers etc listed in the documentation)
- Make a request from your laravel app via `aws php sdk` or `http request`(`guzzle`, `curl`) to your sqs and let lambda to consume your sqs.
- You may use some async driver to trigger your sqs requests asynchronous.
- If you want to use sqs delay queue, **The maximum is 15 minutes** - here for the [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-delay-queues.html)